# How to get REGEXP_LIKE that gets the exact word first, then append all the word related later?

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, sql-like

## Table Desc:

```
id   desc
0    ball
1    basketball
2    ballpen
3    a ball
4    ball pen
```

## table Desired output

```
id    desc  
 0    ball  
 3    a ball  
 4    ball pen  
 2    ballpen  
 1   basketball
```

Even not the same order.
But importantly ill get the exact word first, then followed by all the related word. a ball is still considered exact word so it can be first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two way to return all the rows with the standalone word "ball" first, followed by those that include "ball" within another word.

First up, if you want to ensure row with only "ball" appears first, build a case expression in your sort.

In this check if the value equals your search variable. If it does map to a number such as one. If it doesn't map to a higher number, e.g. two.

To return all the rows that include ball as it's own word, here's two ways:

**regexp_like**

You can use the regular expression:

(^|\s|\W)ball($|\s|\W)

Which in SQL looks like:

```
create table t as 
  select 0 id, 'ball' val from dual union
  select 1, 'basketball' from dual union
  select 2, 'ballpen'    from dual union
  select 3, 'a ball'     from dual union
  select 4, 'ball pen'   from dual union
  select 5, 'littlefoot' from dual;

var v varchar2(10);

exec :v := 'ball';

select * 
from   t
where  val like '%' || :v || '%'
order  by case 
  when val = :v then 1
  when regexp_like ( val, '(^|\s|\W)' || :v || '($|\s|\W)' ) then 2
  else 3
end, id;

ID   VAL          
   0 ball         
   3 a ball       
   4 ball pen     
   1 basketball   
   2 ballpen
```

**Oracle Text**

If you create an Oracle Text index on the column, you can use contains to find matching rows. Call this twice. Once to find exact matches. Then again to show matches with a word.

Then sort by the score of these descending. The exact score first, then the other:

```
create index test_i on t ( val ) indextype is ctxsys.context;

select t.*, score (1), score (2) from t
where  contains ( val, :v, 1 ) > 0
or     contains ( val, '%' || :v || '%', 2 ) > 0
order  by case 
  when val = :v then 1
  else 2
end, score ( 1 ) desc, score ( 2 ) desc;

ID   VAL          SCORE(1)   SCORE(2)   
   0 ball                  4          4 
   3 a ball                4          4 
   4 ball pen              4          4 
   1 basketball            0          4 
   2 ballpen               0          4
```

Comment: (^|\s|\W)ball(basket)($|\s|\W) does this include () ? cos i think it doesntt   thanks :)

Comment: @jojo Does it match the parentheses? No.

Comment: so when i search for ball(basket) which is the exact desc in my db how can i search it? and sometimes i get this unmatched parentheses in regular expression sometimes no result depending on the query

Comment: @jojo ball(basket) matches "ballbasket". If you're unsure what a regex matches, try it out on [regex101](http://regex101.com)

Comment: Thanks. I just need to escape the parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a regular expression, I'd rather suggest something like this: `UTL_MATCH`.

```
SQL> with test (id, c_desc) as
  2  (select 0, 'ball'       from dual union
  3   select 1, 'basketball' from dual union
  4   select 2, 'ballpen'    from dual union
  5   select 3, 'a ball'     from dual union
  6   select 4, 'ball pen'   from dual union
  7   select 5, 'littlefoot' from dual
  8  )
  9  select
 10    id,
 11    c_desc,
 12    utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity (c_desc, '&&par_desc') similarity
 13  from test
 14  where instr(c_desc, '&&par_desc') > 0
 15  order by utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity (c_desc, '&&par_desc') desc;
Enter value for par_desc: ball

        ID C_DESC     SIMILARITY
---------- ---------- ----------
         0 ball              100
         2 ballpen            91
         4 ball pen           89
         3 a ball             80
         1 basketball         65

SQL> undefine par_desc
SQL> /
Enter value for par_desc: pinky

no rows selected

SQL> undefine par_desc
SQL> /
Enter value for par_desc: tle

        ID C_DESC     SIMILARITY
---------- ---------- ----------
         5 littlefoot         65

SQL>
```

Comment: is this available for sql server oracle? plsql

Comment: I don't speak MS SQL Server, but I doubt it; UTL_MATCH is Oracle.